# How to set php array to html element data attribute as javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have custom **array** in php:

```
$tags = [
    'portfolio',
    'material',
    'corporate'
];
```

How I can paste this array as javascript array in HTML element:

```
<div id="template" data-tags='["portfolio", "material", "corporate"]'></div>
```

I must do this task in php file and return to view.

**I tired:**

```
$result = "";
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $result .= '"'.$tag.'",';
}
$result = '<div class="getTags" style="display:none;" data-tags=\'['.$result.']\'></div>'; 
return $result;
```

But here data tags type not an array, it's string. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Try to serialize array (you can use `json_encode()` function) and add it to client side.

Comment: You can create a JSON string from the array in PHP and parse it in JavaScript: `[...document.querySelectorAll('.getTags')].map(el=>[el,JSON.parse(el.getAttribute('data-tags'))])`

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov Serializing is not the same as JSON-encoding

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks, of course, I make an error.)

Comment: Thanks for answers for all.